# Object under mouseDown COCOA

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, mouseevent

I have a pretty simple question for which I could not find a simple answer.
When using cocoa (osx, xcode) and a method called "mouseDown" which detects if mouse has clicked on a view, how to detect on which object mouse has clicked? I just need a class name so I can know if the user has clicked on, for example NSImageView, WebView, NSTextView or on a NSView it self? Or even better, if I have two NSImageViews on my NSView, how to detect on which one it was clicked?

Cheers.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. What are you trying to accomplish at a high level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view mouseDown method, you can call the hitTest: method to get the farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy that was clicked:

So in your view subclass, you could do something like:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    id clickedObject = [self hitTest:[theEvent locationInWindow]];

    if ([clickedObject isKindOfClass:[NSImageView class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Clicked an ImageView");
    } else if ([clickedObject isKindOfClass:[WebView class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Clicked a WebView");
    }
}
```

Your question seems a bit odd though, because normally you don't need to do this hit testing yourself.

If you're trying to get a click event when a particular image is clicked, a better way would be to use a borderless button with an image set and then implementing an action method and connecting that to the button.

Comment: `id clickedObject = [self hitTest:[theEvent locationInWindow]];` This is exactly what I needed